# RelativeLayout as listview item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-relativelayout

Consider following RelativeLayout as list view item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bigfoo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="bigfoo"
        android:textSize="60sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/foo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bigfoo"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="foo"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/foo"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/foo"
        android:text="bar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

After investigating it with `hierarchyviewer` (on device with Android JB/API 17) `bar` gets 0 height.

**Edit:** Expected result: [image: ExpectedResult]

**Question:**  What is the explanation of such relative layout behavior, and
how to fix the layout to achieve layout, that meets requirements: `foo` is in the middle (vertically) of `bigfoo` and `bar` is above `foo`?

Comment: it will really absurd it works for `android:layout_below="@id/foo"`  instead of   `android:layout_above="@id/foo"`. But still the question is why it is happening +1

Comment: @ShakeebShaheen: Do you mean, that it actually works, if I change it to `android:layout_below="@id/foo"`?

Comment: yes exactly ..I copied the xml in my Ide and Changed as I said above. it works as expected

Comment: Strangely it works... but it shouldn't, and I don't understand why.

Comment: Its really strange that  bar gets 0 height for android:layout_above="@id/foo ..plz ans it urself if u find something

Comment: I will, but the only thing left right now, since it isn't obvious is to pull RelativeLayout source, attach to sample project, and step-by-step debug it to find out why it behaves like this. Unfortunately, I don't have time for that right now. But I'll keep this question open - maybe I'll find time to do so...

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 options :

**Option 1**, no nesting (that way bar is on the top of the layout, but you can set a top margin to lower it a bit if that works with your use of the layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bigfoo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="bigfoo"
        android:textSize="60sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/foo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bigfoo"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="foo"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bigfoo"
        android:text="bar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Option 2**, nesting another RelativeLayout in the first one :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bigfoo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="bigfoo"
        android:textSize="60sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/bigfoo"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bigfoo"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bigfoo">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/foo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="foo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/foo"
            android:text="bar" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

With Option 2, you should achieve exactly the result you're expecting, but at the cost of nesting a layout inside another one. If the rest of the UI is light, it shouldn't be a problem ;)

**EDIT** : could you try this, please ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bigfoo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="bigfoo"
        android:textSize="60sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/foo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bigfoo"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="foo"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/foo"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/foo"
        android:text="bar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what I see, although I'd have trouble explaining why this works ...
[image]

Comment: Option1: Inapplicable, as `bar` is not "above" foo, I understand your idea is to tune it slightly with top margin, but it would be device dependent wouldn't it?
Option2: This actually helps a bit, but I wouldn't want to introduce nesting for each list item, my actual layout is a bit more complicated, I stripped it out of unnecessary parts for the means of the question.

Comment: Let's see if someone comes up with a better solution ... Nevertheless, I would test to see if the nesting is impacting performances and if so, try to make the rest of the layout lighter ;)

Comment: I've already coped with this problem in the similar manner, but I'm mostly interested, why RelativeLayout actually behaved so strangely in this case. I looked for someone to say similar to: "onMesure() in this case gave 0 because...", but thanks for your effort anyways!

Comment: See my edited answer, maybe Eclipse preview is just going nuts, or this magically works for some weird reason :-)

Comment: Actually it works, but strangely, if I wanted to add something below `foo` it would be impossible. Nevertheless I'm still interested why relative layout behaves so strange in this condition?

Comment: Well, me too. It seems to be related to the use of layout_centerVertical, although I don't know what exactly causes this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bigfoo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="bigfoo"
        android:textSize="60sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bigfoo"
        android:text="bar"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/foo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/bar"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bigfoo"
        android:text="foo"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer.