# listview in RelativeLayout becomes invisible, how to place a list view in relative layout below is the code

Tags: android, android-listview, android-relativelayout

listview in `RelativeLayout` becomes invisible, how to place a `listview` in `Relativelayout`? Below is the code.

This is the **settings_screen.xml**

its xml code only. Code sections explained carefully please bear with me. For the first time i am posting this code it saying post come cobnntext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/black_background_metal"
 android:orientation="vertical" >
   <!-- this is a image with a text. if this can be relative layout -->
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="50dip" >

           <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imageView1"
             android:layout_width="40dp"
             android:layout_height="40dp"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:scaleType="fitXY"
             android:src="@drawable/settings1" />

           <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="left"
             android:layout_marginTop="60dip"
             android:paddingTop="10dip"
             android:text="@string/settings_label"
             android:textSize="16sp" />
     </LinearLayout>
              <!--  here if i put relativelaout listview becomes invisible-->
     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.91"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
        </ListView>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your code for your activity,is listview is going invisible in the runtime only?

Comment: ReferThis will help you.
 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636734/relativelayout-as-listview-item

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_height="0dip"` and `android:layout_weight="0.91"` won't work with `RelativeLayout`. You will need to use either `android:layout_below` or `android:layout_alignParentBottom`

Answer (score 0):

Relative layout will not support `android:layout_height="0dip"` and `android:layout_weight="0.91"`. Here is the modified xml with relativelayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<!-- this is a image with a text. if this can be relative layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:text="@string/action_settings"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
<!--  here if i put relativelaout listview becomes invisible-->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/linear"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>
```